# NameError when incrementing ascii value, in Python

Tags: python, scope, ascii

When I try to increment the ascii value by 1 of each char in a string, the following error gets thrown:

Error:

```
    line 14, in LetterChanges
    incrementLetter("abc")
    line 11, in incrementLetter
    str2 = str2 + chr(ord(str[i]) + 1) 
    NameError: global name 'str2' it is not defined
```

I believe 'str2' is correctly defined at the beginning and I use the global statement to put it in scope of the function. Why does python believe 'str2' is not defined?

Code:

```
def LetterChanges(str): 

    str2=""

    def incrementLetter(str):
        global str2
        for i in str:
            str2 = str2 + chr(ord(i) + 1) 
            print(str2)

    incrementLetter("abc")
# keep this function call here  
print LetterChanges(raw_input())
```

Comment: Why is there a `return str2` outside of your `def`? Is your shown code a part of another function?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, instead I get a TypeError since you are trying to index `str` (a terrible name choice) with `i`, which is a `str` object, and `str` objects can onlybeindexed by `int` objects

Comment: You **need** to provide a [mcve] for debugging help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use `enumerate`. The way you have it written, `i` is a string and not an integer.

```
def incrementLetter(input_string):
  str2 = ""
  for i, character in enumerate(input_string):
    str2 += chr(ord(input_string[i]) + 1)

  return str2

print(incrementLetter('test'))
```

I would simplify your solution somewhat, though, using list comprehension:

```
def incrementLetter(input_string):
  str2 = ''.join([chr(ord(i) + 1) for i in input_string])
  return str2

print(incrementLetter('test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of errors. This should work

```
str2=""

def incrementLetter(str1):
    global str2
    for i in str1:
        str2 = str2 + chr(ord(i) + 1) 
        print(str2)

incrementLetter("abc")
```

OR

One liner

```
print(''.join(map(chr,(i+1 for i in map(ord,"abc")))))
```